# Apache Httpclient Connection not Released

Tags: java, httpclient

I am using spring rest template to send REST request with apache http client 4.2.1 intergrated.

As we need send request to multiple server, added PoolingClientConnectionManager to manager the connections.

Set the max per route to 5
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5)

While after the system running for few days, we found that the connection reached the maxmium per route settings.

Printed log as below
total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 5 of 5; total allocated: 5 of 100

Seems the connection is not released by some reason. But when i debug, i found every time after request is finished, the connection will be released even there's exception happens.

Is there any other potential root cause of this connection cannot be released?

Comment: Could it be, that your release of connections just returns them to the pool?

Comment: I called release, the connection will release to the pool

Comment: That's how pools normally work.

Comment: Might be worth checking if there's any path that ignores the response payload; I faced such a "connection not released" issue when I was only reading the status codes of some responses and just ignoring the response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in some case, the server hold the request, we need add timeout for http client