# HttpClient class AbstractConnPool becames too big,how to solve it ？

Tags: java, httpclient

The class [`org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.4.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/pool/AbstractConnPool.html#setMaxTotal(int)) has this map field：

```
private final Map<T, RouteSpecificPool<T, C, E>> routeToPool;
```

If I use a lot of proxy ip, the map size will became bigger and bigger, this will cause  oom.

How to solve it?

Comment: Seems this is a result of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081378/httpclient-out-of-memory

Comment: Asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081378/httpclient-out-of-memory) again without further info will not result in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I never had this issue working with an Apache HTP Client. Looking at your memory dump at [Httpclient out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081378/httpclient-out-of-memory) I see "`104655 instances of class org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$1`" which is an anon inner implementation of `RouteSpecificPool` which is the value type of the field you mentioned.

So the question is, how do you use the client? The connections **have to be released** at some point and unused and/or expired connections will be cleaned up.

Do never keep connections in the pool forever or do a keep alive for connections you do not use any more! Such things in combination with requests to high diverse targets (aka routes). You have to configure timeouts for usages (see also [Apache Httpclient Connection not Released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635232/apache-httpclient-connection-not-released))!

Comment: Thank you,the question you mentioned is mine ,I have solved it.Because I use a lot of proxy IPs, these IPs participate in the calculation of the hash value  together with the target address, resulting in routeToPool getting larger and larger.The method closeExpiredConnections() and closeIdleConnections() of HttpClientConnectionManager  can release unused connections in  the field routeToPool.But I have to call them periodically.